# How to discard of ashes when in a wilderness cabin?

Tags: fire, leave-no-trace

I was staying in the spectacular [free and open](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/4214/566) Ragohytte in magnificent [Rago Nasjonalpark](http://www.miljodirektoratet.no/Global/dokumenter/Publikasjoner/Brosjyrer/Rago_NP_E%20mai%202011.pdf), and used some of the provided firewood and coal to heat up the stove in order to dry my gear and enjoy a bit of warmth (before the weather improved).  I should and do carry non-burnable waste down (I left some copies of a non-local hiking book for tinder).  Literally, non-burnable waste includes ashes, but I believe people do not carry ashes down from the mountain.

[image: Ragohytte in Rago Nasjonalpark, 10 September 2016]
Ragohytte in Rago Nasjonalpark, 10 September 2016

What is the proper way to dispose of ashes and remains of coal and firewood?

[image: Ragohytte seen from a distance]
  The same but seen from a distance